# How to isolate this enumerator that counts up for each field?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have the following code:

```
countSetNumbers = ->
  for field, i in $(".exercise .nested-fields")
    set = $(field).find('.set')
    set.html(i+1)
```

The issue is I have multiple .exercise divs and instead of each exercise being isolated in the amount of set #'s... it's counting all the exercises together as a lump. So if exercise 1 has 3 sets, and exercise 2 had 1. The first set of exercise 2 would be labeled `4`. How do I make it so each one is counted unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're mashing all the `.nested-fields` elements into one pile when you say:

```
$(".exercise .nested-fields")
```

You need to consider each `.exercise` separately. One simple way to do that is to break the selector in half and use a nested loop:

```
countSetNumbers = ->
  for ex in $('.exercise')
    for nf, i in $(ex).find('.nested-fields')
      $(nf).find('.set').html(i + 1)
```

That assumes an HTML structure something like this:

```
<div class="exercise">
    <div class="nested-fields">
        <div class="set"></div>
    </div>
    <!--...-->
</div>
<!--...-->
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LekpV/

You could also do it jQuery-style:

```
countSetNumbers = ->
  $('.exercise').each ->
    $(@).find('.nested-fields').each (i) ->
      $(@).find('.set').html(i + 1)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Au7rs/1/